# Eclipse - properties to uppercase

Tags: eclipse, properties

I have to change the case (to uppercase) for a lot of entries in a properties file. Is there an easy way to do this using the Eclipse properties editor? The standard (based on internet search) ctrl + shift + x key combination is not working.
Thanks!

Comment: **ctrl + shift + x** works for me on Photon, but here are a couple of alternative approaches: [1] Select the text to be converted to upper case, then position the mouse over the selected text, right-click and from the context menu select **Convert > To Upper Case**. [2] Select the text to be converted to uppercase then **ctrl + alt + u**. I just verified both approaches so if you still have problems then update your post with the issues you faced.

Comment: Working. Thanks. Can you create an answer from your comment? Then I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ctrl + shift + x** works for me on Photon, but here are a couple of alternative approaches:

- Select the text to be converted to upper case, then position the mouse over the selected text, right-click and from the context menu select **Convert > To Upper Case**.
- Select the text to be converted to uppercase then **ctrl + alt + u**. You can also use **ctrl + alt + l** to toggle to lower case.

To research why **ctrl + shift + x** is not working for you:

- List the current key bindings in Eclipse using **Window > Preferences > General > Keys**
- The list of key bindings will be displayed in the panel on the right. Click *Binding* in the header columns to sort the list by binding value.
- Scroll down and locate the entry for **ctrl + shift + x**, which should be for the *To Upper Case* command.
- If there are any conflicts they will be shown in the conflicts panel:

  [image: EclipseBindings]
- Click the **Help** button in the bottom left corner of the screen for details on resolving conflicts with key bindings.
- To revert to Eclipse's default setting for the *To Upper Case* command:

  - Select its entry in the list of commands.
  - Click the **Restore Command** button.
  - Click the **Apply** button.